# Why does my model enlarge when I add automatic weights?

Tags: mesh, weight-painting, unity, rigify, makehuman

I used this tutorial to create a human model for a school project. 
I followed every step, but when I reach the part where I have to skin the model, it seems to go completely wrong.

I select the body and its skeleton in object mode, then press ctrl+P >> with automatic weights. After that the body suddenly enlarges but the skeleton remains the same size.

I made this model in MakeHuman and had to scale it down because my armature wasn't big enough. I tried ctrl+A and selected scale, but then I get a bunch of lines sticking out of the body.

Could anyone help me fix this? Or at least explain what (might) be the problem? And also tell me what skinning and weight painting does. The that I found articles on internet didn't really help.

I want to export this to Unity so that I can use it in a game. I am not that experienced with Blender btw.

[image]

[image: This is how I end up when I add automatic weights]

Comment: to get help with your model you got from makehuman, you need to share it... one way is using http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I got the file but I still can't understand what happens exactly, sorry. Can you show before/after images to make what happens?

Comment: Done, btw I can't post more than two links in my question... So here's the link to the tutorial I followed (just to be sure) http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/BlenderAndRigify.html